# Utility for extracting MIME attachments

Tags: command-line, email, debian, extract, mime-types

I am looking for a command-line tool for Unix (ideally, available in a Debian / Ubuntu package) for extracting all MIME parts from a multipart email message (or the body from a singlepart with an interesting content-type, for that matter).

I have been using the `mimeexplode` tool which ships with the Perl [MIME::Tools](http://search.cpan.org/~eryq/MIME-tools/) package, but it's not really production quality (the script is included as an example only, and has issues with what it regards as "evil" character sets) and I could certainly roll my own script based on that, but if this particular wheel has already been innovated, perhaps I shouldn't.

Comment: Via another question I came across http://www.pldaniels.com/ripmime/ which looks very nice, but it's not available as an Ubuntu package as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[munpack](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/munpack.1.html) from mpack worked for me

In Debian/Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install mpack
munpack -f mime-attachments-file
```

Comment: Overall a nice solution.  Still, as of version 1.6, it does not cope correctly with `=<cr><lf>` sequences in quoted-printable text (I get a spurious 0xFF byte for each escaped line break in the input).  This seems to have been reported in 2011, but still not fixed: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=647180

Comment: Did not recognize the filename of my pdf attachement.

Answer (score 20):

The [mu project](https://code.google.com/p/mu0/) seems to include a [mu-extract](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/mu-extract.1.html) command that looks as if it might do what you want.  And it appears to be available as an Ubuntu package already.

NB: I haven't actually used this tool myself.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install maildir-utils && mu extract -a <file>`

Comment: `mu: error: init_mime_msg: cannot construct mime message for noname.eml`

Comment: If that's a question, you probably want to post an actual question.  This answer is over two years old.

Comment: This is the tool of choice I would say. You can even select the attachement by regular expression. Cf. https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/cheatsheet.html

Answer (score 1):

I needed to unpack a chrome dmp file in order to extract the minidump for analysis on Ubuntu 12.04.4. I found that the mime file had been written in DOS format despite being in a Linux environment, so neither mpack or maildir-utils worked out of the box. The following steps worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix mpack
cp chromium-renderer-minidump-c3303784f176fb58.dmp backup
dos2unix -f chromium-renderer-minidump-c3303784f176fb58.dmp
munpack chromium-renderer-minidump-c3303784f176fb58.dmp
```

The -f on dos2unix is required to force the conversion on a binary file. The maildir-utils mu program crashed trying to read the dmp file even after dos2unix conversion.

Answer (score -4):

- mpack tools, and munpack
- GNU base64 decoder
- mimedecode
- mha-decode
- UUDeview
- OpenSSL

Comment: -1 I am familiar with all of these except mha-decode and mimedecode, and at least none of the others accept an email message as input, and produces its attachments as output. I will take a look at mha-decode and mimedecode, still.